# Modeling the sum of binary variables

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, binary-variable

Suppose $x_{1},x_{2}, \cdots ,x_{n}$ are binaries.

I would like to model the following:

IF $x_{1} + x_{2}+ \cdots +x_{n} \ge 2$ THEN $x_{1} + x_{2} = 2$

IF $x_{1} + x_{2}+ \cdots +x_{n} \ge 3$ THEN $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3}= 3$

and so on.

Is there a better way than asking for the following

$(x_{1} \ge 1) \lor (x_{1} + x_{2} \ge 2) \lor (x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} \ge 3) \cdots $, which then requires the introduction of additional binaries?

Comment: I think you need another clause in the disjunction: $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 0$.  Otherwise, $x_1=1$ is forced.

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does $x_i \ge x_{i+1}$ do what you want?

Comment: That's genius...

Comment: Thank you Rob. This is what I already have implemented. I hoped, that is the purpose of the question, I can do something without having to wait for the end of the optimisation run. I mean, if I have the constraint x1 + x2 + x3 => 2 then in a relaxation it can be satisfied as (x1,x2,x3) = (0.8,0.7,0.5), which satisfies the requirement x(i) => x(i+1) but not x1+x2=2.

Comment: Looks like the simple formulation already yields the integer hull, so you will not get anything stronger unless you consider the other constraints in your model.

Comment: Then I can stop looking for something better. Thank you again Rob.